# Access column from top query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I try to run following query:

```
select * 
  from tbl1
 where tbl1.clmn = (select * 
                      from (select val 
                              from tbl2 
                             where tbl2.clmn2 = tbl1.val
                             order by tbl2.order)
                     where rownum <=1)
```

But `tbl1.val` is not accessible in the sub-query. Is it possible to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to convert subquery to join.

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl1 t1 INNER JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM tbl2 ORDER BY tbl2.order) t WHERE t.rownum <= 1
) t2 ON t2.clmn2=t1.val
```

You might need to make it work on Oracle, but generally you should go this way.

Comment: I do not want to join `tbl1` and `tbl2`. Actually `tbl2` is a result of another join which is quite expensive. And by accessing `tbl1.val` I could restrict this join for the specific `tbl1.val`

Answer (score 0):

In oracle prior to 12c we can reference a table in a correlated sub-query that is only one level deep, no more(ANSI standard). In 12c, though, we can go more than 2 levels deep. So, in your situation, if you are so against table joining, the two-level correlated sub-query can be rewritten as follows:

```
select *
  from tbl1
 where tbl1.clmn = (select max(tbl2.val) keep(dense_rank first 
                                                   order by tbl2.order)
                      from tbl2
                     where tbl2.clmn2 = tbl1.val )
```